Nach mehrfach Nutzung von "jeder" steht Verb im Singular oder Plural?
"Jeder Mensch und jedes Tier hat eine eigene Geschichte" aber "ein Mensch und ein Tier haben eine eigene Geschichte" warum steht das Verb im ersten Satz im Singular und und im 2.im Plural

"Jeder" ist bei Aufzählungen ein Indikator für die Nutzung von Verben im Singular
Hier ist ein hilfreicher Artikel von der Website des Duden, der sich mit dem Thema auseinandersetzt.
https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/%E2%80%9Esowohl-als-auch%E2%80%9C-%E2%80%93-Singular-oder-Plural-Auf%C2%ADz%C3%A4hlung%C2%ADen
Für dich lässt sich das zu folgender Regel zusammenfassen:
Generell wird der Plural für Verben genutzt, die sich auf die Bestandteile von Aufzählungen beziehen. Aber es gibt Ausnahmen, welche erlernt werden müssen. Der Artikel des Duden listet diese Ausnahmen auf.
